# <ObjectType> in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, generics, nsarray

In NSArray.h I saw the interface like this

```
@interface NSArray<ObjectType>
```

What is the significance of `<ObjectType>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is Apple using lightweight generics.  The full `@interface` declaration in Xcode 7.3.1 looks like this:

```
@interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>
```

`ObjectType` is a placeholder used to represent the generic argument you pass into so that the compiler knows where to reference them.  This is different than using `NSObject *` because `ObjectType` is like `id`, it can refer to non-Objective-C pointer types such as CoreFoundation objects.

For example, if I wanted to create a class that mocks an array for only a specific class, I could do something like `@interface MYArray<MyClass *>`.

You could also specifically declare an array of strings as `NSArray<NSString *>`.

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425225429/http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/) on Objective-C Generics for more information.